# Extra New Lines Being Printed When replacing <br> with '\n' in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a little assistance. I am converting br tag to '\n' using javascript. But it is placing extra '\n' characters in place of the present number of br tags...

The following text

```
dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text <br><br>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text
```

is being replaced by

```
dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text 



dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text
```

I have tried many regular expressions and stuff available here on stackoverflow but all of them printing extra newlines.

Here is the expression that i am using at the moment.

```
str.replace(/<br>/g,'\n')
```

It happens Specially the content of the text box is loaded through nl2br in php.

See the following images.

This is when the page is loaded
[image: This is when the page is loaded]

This is when the edit is pressed and str.replace thing is called.
[image: This is when the edit is pressed and str.replace thing is called.]

Can anyone tell where I am making the mistake?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please set up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating the problem?

Comment: will not be able to JSFiddle because when simply js is applied the issue is not there. The issue comes when the content of the text area are loaded through php using nl2br...

Comment: I have updated the question, please refresh the page and see a couple of snaps that I have added for your assistance.

Comment: nl2br **adds** the <br> (so the function should be called differently in the first place), so maybe you can just remove the <br>? Or don't have them inserted in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

PHP's `nl2br` doesn't *replace* newlines, it simply adds `<br />` tags to the existing newlines.

When your JS tries to "reverse" the operation, it results in the original newline being duplicated.

Your replacement should replace with the empty string to remove the `<br />` tags.

Consider also using the CSS `white-space: pre-wrap` *instead of* `nl2br`, as this will preserve all whitespace, including newlines and multiple spaces!

Comment: so what will this line become now? <p id="dummy_objective"><?php echo nl2br($resume_objective_id);?></p>

Comment: Just remove the `nl2br` function call.

Comment: it doesnt work for my case because when i load the page it has to have line breaks because when the page is loaded, it is a disabled textbox having the content. When the edit button is pressed, the textarea becomes editable and br tags are replaced by new lines. pre-wrap doesnt do the job. It is just printing extra '\n' characters for every br...makes sense?

Comment: Because you're still using `nl2br`. Remove it!

Answer (score 1):

simply use

```
replace(/<br\s*\/?>\n/mg,"\n")
```